# What does it mean "IDF is just dependent on the term"?

Tags: information-retrieval, tf-idf, data-retrieval

it possible someone explain "Tf is dependent on term and document" and  "IDF is just dependent on the term" with an example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that we have these two documents:

```
d_1: "Tf is dependent on term and document"
d_2: "IDF is just dependent on the term"
```

The count of terms in each document is as follows:

```
d_1: 
{Tf: 1, is: 1, dependent: 1, on: 1, term: 1, and: 1, document: 1}
d_2:
{IDF: 1, is: 1, just: 1, dependent: 1, on: 1, the: 1, term: 1}
```

The term frequencies (i.e., the ratio of times that term t appears in document d to the total count of terms of that document) for term "on" are:

```
tf(on, d_1) = 1 / 7
tf(on, d_2) = 1 / 7
```

For calculating the term frequency of a term, you must specifiy which document you are talking about. tf(on, d_1) = 1/7 tells you that 1/7 of all words in d_1 is "on".

The inverse document frequency (logarithm of ratio of documents that include the word "on") is:

```
idf(on) = log(2/2) = 0
```

As you see, the idf is constant for all documents in this corpus of two documents. It's just a measure of how common a term is in a set of documents. idf(on) = 0 tells you that "on" is not special at all and it appears in all documents.

Comment: is it possible to have negative IDF?

Comment: No. idf(t) = log N/n(t) (where N is the total number of documents, and n(t) is number of documents where t appears. For idf(t) to be negative, you must have log N/n(t) < 0, or log N - log n(t) < 0, or N < n(t), which is impossible (the number of documents with t in them cannot be more than the number of all documents).